# SQL query over several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query with SQL but I don't know how to implement it.

I have given 4 tables with company_ID, reporting year, type_ID and turnover of the company. The values of each company are queried every year, but it is possible that the company does not have a turnover every year or it is also possible that there is no turnover for a company for the whole time. And and it is valid that T1.CompanyID = T2/T3/T4.CompanyID

So now I want to query when is the latest year, as max(ReportingYear), where a turnover is specified and use this reporting year, turnover and CompanyType. If a company had no sales at all over time, the most recent ReportingYear and the associated CompanyType.

I would need these values in the final query:

```
       T1.Company_ext,
       T2.taxID,
       T3.ReportingYear,
       T3.CompanyType,
       T4.Turnover, 
       T4.ReportingYear
```

With this query I got the companies that ever had any turnover at all.

```
SELECT 
       T2.taxID, max(T4.ReportingYear) AS Max_Report
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.CompanyID = T2.CompanyIDc.Id
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.CompanyID = T3.CompanyIDc.Id
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T1.CompanyID = T4.CompanyIDc.Id AND T4.ReportingYear = T3.ReportingYear
WHERE T4.Turnover IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T2.taxID
```

My thought now was that the total quantity - quantity of the above query, must be the ones that had no turnover, however this query runs way too long. Does anyone know a faster way to get the result I want?

The tables look as follows: (In T4 the values I want are marked)

T1:

| CompanyID | CompanyId_ext |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 |
| 124 | 6 |
| 125 | 7 |

T2:

| CompanyID | taxID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1852 |
| 124 | 1935 |
| 125 | 1354 |

T3:

| CompanyID | AttributeID | ReportingYear | CompanyType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 857269 | 2022 | Public |
| 123 | 857269 | 2021 | Not Public |
| 124 | 857270 | 2022 | Not Public |
| 124 | 857270 | 2021 | Public |
| 125 | 857271 | 2022 | Not Public |
| 125 | 857271 | 2021 | Not Public |

T4:

| CompanyID | Turnover | ReportingYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **123** | **1000** | **2022** |
| 123 | NULL | 2021 |
| 124 | NULL | 2022 |
| **124** | **500** | **2021** |
| **125** | **NULL** | **2022** |
| 125 | NULL | 2021 |

Comment: Off-topic: It doesn't appear meaningful to me to have explicit `NULL`s in table T4 – I'd rather drop the rows entirely (or at least rather set zero as value). If you need the nulls in a query anyway you can get them back with left/right joins.

Comment: The table design looks questionable to me at all. Attribute id does not seem to change over the years, so rather a 1:1 relation ship to companyid, additionally T1 and T2 seem to impose 1:1 relation ships as well. **If** all this indeed applies you're better off to combine T1, T2 and T3.attributeid in a single table. The remaining company type might possibly be moved into T4, making T3 obsolete entirely.

Comment: I agree you should probably combine some of these tables, and once you have done that we need to see what indexes you have on the tables, and what is the current execution plan, please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the CompanyID, the CompanyType and the highest ReportingYear with a Turnover (meaning Turnover != NULL), then this is how you could implement it:

```
SELECT T4.CompanyID, MAX(T4.ReportingYear), T3.CompanyType
FROM T4
JOIN T3 ON T4.CompanyID = T3.CompanyID
WHERE T4.Turnover != NULL
```

Comment: We'd yet need to combine this with a left/right join on the other tables replacing the default null values appropriately (COALESCE or specifically MSSQL: ISNULL).